# Ruling on iqamah for Qadha prayers

Tags: fiqh, salat-qada

Assalanualaikum,

I have had a lot of Qadha prayers that have piled up over the past few weeks.
I tried to segment them and make them up, but due to exhaustion and my current schedule I haven't been able to cover them.
I have been trying to pray the fardh and cover the qadha when I can, shall I continue doing this or am I able to pray my regular prayers and then add nafl to make up for the qadha. As the amount of qadha prayers can be overwhelming?

But I completely understand if I should just continue praying Fardh and cover the Qadha until it is complete.

JazakAllah Khairun

Comment: Please click on the tag [tag:salat-qada] and you'll find related answers as your question was already answered on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah keep praying your daily prayers on time everyday, but replace the sunnat e ghair e muhakada and nafls with your qadha prayers.